# How to use initializer as Closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to pass an initializer as a parameter to a function?

```
class A {
    var num: Int
    init() {
        num = 3
    }
}

func f(# createA: () -> A) -> A {

   return createA()
}


f(createA: A)   // This does not work
```

**Update**

Thank you for The Paramagnetic Croissant's answer:

```
f(createA: { A() }) // Correct
```

But what if the initializer has an input?

```
class A {
    var num: Int
    init(a : Int) {
        num = 3
    }
}
func f(# createA: (a: Int) -> A) -> A {

    return createA(a: 1)
}

let a = f(createA: {A(a: Int)}) // Wrong
```

**Update**
OK I figured out:

```
f(createA: { a in A(a: a) })
```

Comment: `f(createA: { A() })`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Thank you! What if the initializer has an input?

Comment: What did you pass into that input?

Comment: @Sen well, obviously then you pass the input to the initializer? or what do you mean?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I have updated the question

Comment: @Sen it seems that you don't know what the difference between an expression and a type is. You need `f(createA: { A(1) })` then. But this is too basic, please read about the fundamentals of the language before asking.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant This does not work, I need to pass a closure as a parameter, but { A(1) } is not a closure. A(1) is an instance of class A

Comment: @Sen `{ A(1) }` **is** a closure. `A(1)` is not the same as `{ A(1) }`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  but `f(createA: { A(1) })` seems not work

Comment: @Sen please clarify. "does not work" is not a helpful problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Swift 2.0 beta (don't know about 1.2):

```
func f(createA createA: () -> A) -> A {
    return createA()
}


f(createA: A.init)
```